# Shared Preferences Login

Tags: android

I would like to make a SharedPreference for my Login. I tried it, but it doesn't work. I am not getting an error in the Logcat. 
My String Variables "email" and "password" have a value.
But when I put this variables to my SharedPreferences, the two variables "user" and "passw" are empty.

```
        CheckBox checkBoxRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRememberLogin);
        if(checkBoxRememberMe.isChecked()){

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("EMAIL", email);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("PASSWORD", password);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("REMEMBERLOGIN", true);
            sharedPreferences.edit().commit();

            user = sharedPreferences.getString("EMAIL", "");
            passw = sharedPreferences.getString("PASSWORD", "");
            System.out.println("---------------" + email + "-----" + password + "-----------");
            System.out.println("---------------" + user + "-----" + passw + "------------");
    }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: where is the user?

Comment: just use .commit() after sharedPreferences.edit().putString(...);

Answer (score 4):

Change to

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("EMAIL", email).commit(); 
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("PASSWORD", password).commit(); 
sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("REMEMBERLOGIN", true).commit();
```

You can also do something like:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("EMAIL", email); 
editor.putString("PASSWORD", password); 
editor.putBoolean("REMEMBERLOGIN", true); 
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thats right :) or you can use apply() as is not common to use commit at this time

Comment: Thanks for your Help community! sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Key", val).commit();  worked